# If $\sin x + \sin y =1/2$ and $\cos x + \cos y =\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Equation 1
$$2\sin\frac{x+y}{2} \cos \frac{x-y}{2}=1/2$$
Equation 2
$$2\cos \frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}=\frac{\sqrt  3}{2}$$dividing them gives 
$$\tan \frac{x+y}{2}=\frac1{\sqrt 3}$$

$$x+y=60$$

Putting this in 1

$$\cos \frac{x-y}{2}=1/2$$
$$x-y=120$$
Thus $x=90$ and $y=-30$

$$3x+y=270-30=240$$ but the answer is 90. What is going wrong?

Comment: You should have $(x+y)/2=60^o,$ not $x+y=60^o.$

Comment: $tan 30 =\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}$

Answer (score 1):

Without further restrictions

$a=\frac{(x+y)}{2}=180^\circ n+30^\circ$

$b=\frac{(x-y)}{2}=360^\circ m\pm60^\circ$

where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers

$3x+y=3(a+b)+(a-b)=?$